# footer.php not getting hooked in the website page. Works fine separately

Tags: php

the footer.php file works fine when opened separately but it's not getting hooked in the main website page.

header.php and sidebar.php are getting hooked

If I move the code present in footer.php to sidebar.php then the footer gets displayed.
If I just cut and paste the code in footer.php directly to index .php. the footer gets displayed.

I even created a new file and added the code from footer.php and hooked that file in it still doesn't work.

```
    <footer class="blog-footer">
    <p>Blog template built for <a 
href="https://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a> by <a 
href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Back to top</a>
    </p>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/docs/4.2/assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="/docs/4.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The code is not interpreted? What is the behavior you are expecting. In the code view (dev tools) the footer tag is not present? Or is present but outside the body tag...If this is the content of the file footer.php. the problem is you are closing the body tag

Comment: make sure your markup is correct, e.g. you could run the source (View Page Source in browser) through a validator [markup validation service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options)

Comment: Explain what you mean by “getting hooked” in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use?

```
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```